# Why are G and H used for feedback block diagrams?

Tags: control, control-system, feedback

The symbols \$G\$ and \$H\$ are typically used for the forward gain and feedback fraction in negative feedback block diagrams like this:

[image]

The choice of \$G\$ is, I suppose, an obvious one, meant to be mnemonic for *gain*.

But \$H\$ I don't get. Is it just because it's the next letter in the alphabet and maybe \$F\$ was already taken? Or is there perhaps a historical reason that might lead one to see it as a less arbitrary choice?

---

***Note:***
I understand these symbols are not universally used in these roles. I kind of grew up on \$A_o\$ and \$\beta\$ myself, but as I understand it, \$G\$ and \$H\$ are more common in the control systems world and do have some advantages over other choices. Certainly conforming to a convention has its own benefits, whatever that convention is.

Comment: Hysteresis? Heuristic?

Comment: Hmm. I'll guess that Harold Black popularized it and managed to sneak his first initial in there, besides. ;) Of course, I've no clue at all.

Comment: $H(\cdot)$ is commonly used to refer to the transfer function of e.g. n LTI system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function

Comment: @Math1000: Hmm, that's right, I hadn't made that connection. I wonder if that has to do with it, like the transfer function of the feedback network or something. Although in a block diagram of any complexity there are a lot of transfer functions around :). And then of course, it raises the question of how \$H\$ was chosen for that role :)

Comment: Do you have an example because I see something different i.e. H is used as in H(s) for the overall transfer function.

Comment: [Here's one](http://www.planetanalog.com/author.asp?section_id=3049&doc_id=564024) I happened to be reading today. The author also offers a point of view on symbol choice (i.e. preference for these particular two) in the section called "Academic Aside".

Answer (score 3):

"H" isn't Abbreviation something special . 
this just a symbol for feedback . like "beta". but i think this method of  Nomination should be something like declare a variable like u declare "X" and other variable is "y" and this is "G" for gain and next alphabet of that is "H".

Comment: At first I thought this unlikely, but based on some videos I've been watching on control systems, I'm starting to think assigning symbols in these block diagrams *is* actually fairly arbitrary and generally in sequence. It makes more sense when you have a block diagram with a dozen blocks in it and need more symbols (or have to resort to subscripts). So you might have G, H, K, M, N, P, Q, R etc. I'm thinking I, J, L, O and a few others are avoided to avoid confusion with current, inductance, and zero :). Anyway, not definitive, but starting to make more sense than it did to me originally :)